# Xcode 4.4.1: git no longer showing modifications

Tags: xcode, git

Suddenly, unfortunately, I can't place the moment of occurrence Xcode has stopped showing git information, nor can I submit/revert/etc via git from inside Xcode. If I check the Organizer's Repositories, my project is still listed with its last commit.

Using the command line: git status, I see all the unstaged changes as I would expect.

So, the project is still under git control, but somehow detached from Xcode.

Comment: You are using hombrew's git, right? (or maybe have installed the Xcode 4.5 cli)? Is your project using submodules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by going to Organizer in Xcode, selecting my project, and deleting the Derived Data. You may need to quit Xcode and re-open your project after doing this to let Xcode rebuild the project index.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the command line tools worked for me