# How to resych xcode and Git

Tags: xcode, git

I had a power failure while using xcode. I use Git and Time Machine. When my machine came back up, and I restarted xcode, most of my project files are marked with a status of '?'. There are some that are incorrectly marked as 'M'. I tried doing a commit but got an error consisting of a list of my project files that were supposedly not being tracked by Git (the list was not correct) and the commit failed.

After reading some entries on SO I exited xcode and tried

```
git stash
git reset --hard cf530af
git stash pop
```

This left me with short list of modified and deleted files which was correct. But when I restarted xcode the file stats icons were unchanged.

Next I exited xcode and restored last night's Time Machine backup. That went smoothly, but when I restarted xcode, the file status icons were still incorrect.

At the moment, `git status` shows results I believe to be correct. `git fsck` shows a number of dangling blobs and 1 dangling commit.

What do I need to do to resynch xcode and Git so I can git back to work?

Comment: Since I believed what was on the disk to be correct, I deleted the existing .git directory, (re)created a new git repository and added all my current project files to it. It just seems kind of silly to have turned on all this protection and then have it not work when I needed it.

Comment: My suspicion there would be squarely on xcode.

Comment: If you kept a backup, you might be able to look at questions such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940564/xcode-4-4-1-git-no-longer-showing-modifications?rq=1 to find out if they were what you were experiencing.

Comment: Thanks, Arafangion. Actually, something similar to what is described in that post happened to me a few months ago. I was even newer to xcode and git and assumed that I had done something wrong. If I had seen that post I'm not sure I would have had the courage to delete git's Derived Data. My solution at the time was to manually inspect and copy each file in my project to a new project, and start over. It seems SCM is still not simple, and the level of protection it has provided does not motivate me to learn too much more about it.

Comment: If you kept backups, (Which you have said you do), then you have no reason to feel frightened deleting git's Derived Data.  The worst that could happen is that you would have to restore from your backups.