# How do I convince Xcode and Git that my Asset Catalog has been updated?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, xcode5, asset-catalog

After adding new image sets and images to my asset catalog, Xcode doesn't seem to think it needs committing to Git.

[image: No M flag]

Occasionally it'll notice the change if I quit Xcode and restart it, but that seems a little unreliable.

Or am I missing something obvious?

**UPDATE:** The 'M' has appeared! It seems performing a `git pull` has made it realise there's been a local change (?!).

I've cured the symptom, but can anyone explain the root cause?

[image]

Comment: I vaguely remember a "copy into folder" option when you are adding files in xcode. Do these files physically exist at this location? Verify with command line or whatever the finder.

Comment: @JohnnyZ - Yup, the images are where they should be, next to the groups 'Contents.json' file. (I have forgotten to tick the 'copy' box before, so I know what you mean though)

Comment: another debugging step: run `git status` from a command line in a situation where you don't see the 'M'. What is the result?

Comment: Interesting - It shows 4 new added files; the two new images and their associated contents.json.

Comment: Looks like it is an xcode problem. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940564/xcode-4-4-1-git-no-longer-showing-modifications

Comment: I took a brave pill and deleted the derived data as that question suggested, but no dice. I wonder if I'm mistaken and never saw the mystical 'M' next to the asset catalog before?

Comment: Some solution about this?

Answer (score 0):

Hit the **build/run button**. Sometimes git needs a little push to understand that things may have changed. If it's not working, try to rename something or even changing some variable name into your code.